# Is this considered a valid question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871328/reverse-a-string-c):

[image]

More undebugged code follows up.

Since when is such considered a valid question for Stack Overflow?

1. *"I have researched"* Obviously not.
2. It's a simple-to-solve problem with having everything needed at hand.
3. In which way is this supposed to help future researchers?

So why any upvotes there? I well understand people trying to answer the question tend to upvote it, also I see that *"Let's be friendly with newbies effect"* (I call these *Robo Upvoters* usually) very often.

Still questionable is, is that particular piece a valid question? Should we edit it, to make it valid and helpful for future research?

Comment: Oh your downvote is visible in the screenshot, Brace yourself...Serial downvoting storm is expected.. :p

Comment: @nobalG Doubt that. And if so, what should I care about such?! Of course I have downvoted and close voted the question, did I leave any doubts about this?

Comment: No you didn't, actually I have seen other questions on meta suffering from this.. :p

Comment: Just vote to close it and move along. The dramatics seem misplaced. It's a bad question... we've got gobs of them. We've got bad questions coming out of our eyeballs. Please don't take them personally. Downvote, vote to close, next! You could also hang out in one of the various chat rooms, if you find an especially egregious question one can paste a link to it, raising the visibility and thus speed which it is closed. A meta post about a bad question is most unnecessary. No one can know why people upvote garbage, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Judging by the OPs comments, the intentions were good and they show a clear desire to improve going forward. I quote: "πάντα ῥεῖ, thanks for the heads up. I as for forgiveness from all. I am totally ignorant to the ways of StackOverFlow". Maybe something more constructive would be helpful to go along with all the downvotes guys?

Comment: Let the guy ask what he wants, if its a coding question its a coding question. Who are you to judge if question is bad or not.. What you are doing here isnt a damn question and should deserve more downvotes than that guy...

Comment: This is not a discussion board or a forum, its questions and answers. if you wanna start a debate go to fb or twitter..

Comment: @emotality What you're saying is a bit contradictorily, since we have the [tag:discussion] and [tag:specific-question] tags here. Also I don't see how this should be an invalid question on MSO?!? Who are you actually judging me for my judgement? We're encouraged moderating the site ourselves. That's all I'm doing.

Comment: Oh I didn't know its MSO, my bad.. But I still think he needed to know how its done, he might have no background in this language and still learning. We were all there, everyone needs to start somewhere, give him a break. :)

Comment: @emotality It turned out to be a dupe actually, so what? Should I remove my question on MSO? It just shows, how a question was correctly handled by the system. Most probably the original question will be deleted soon by the system.

Comment: Did you mean "came *across* this question"?

Comment: I think the real problem with the question it is posed as "solve my interview question" when in reality it is strictly almost ok "why my code does not work" question. The sample code outlines what should happen and only missing part is clearly specified bug in the code (somewhat hinted, but hard to see).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov At least with the latest edits, I can't spot any mention of _'interview question'_. It turned out there are numb of duplicates, and the question was closed likely. (I hope you have fresh eggs while reading 2 days old newspapers for breakfast :P ...)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - image in your post shows "intervew question", but even without it many people seen this and would read it as if it asks about interview question :). (BTW it is not my fault your post mentioned on Hot Meta posts).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ooops, of course yes! It's not your fault, but mine (or hot meta algo's showing "solved" questions). Yes, the original question mentioning the _interview question_ might have helped closing the question. Though we were lucky to find dupes for it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question is bad. Not *terrible* (it does show an attempt and has a clear problem statement), but it isn't very good. Does it meet the criteria for downvoting? Probably.

However, everyone can vote any direction for any reason. The upvotes *could* have been:

- The answerers, either because they truly feel its a good question, or so the question gets more attention (and their posts are more likely to get upvotes)
- People that think "we should be nice to newbies" and so upvote every new user's post they find
- People that truly think its a well-put, useful question.

Comment: The first two groups should push that consideration into polishing the question so it deserves an upvote instead. (The first is tactical voting, though not quite at its worst, the second a complete mis-understanding what voting is about.) No way to quibble with those voting for the third point though. And you are right all three happen...

Comment: Just to add: The question seems to ask for how to reverse a string (which the OP solved), but actually asks how to do so word-wise. Anyway, both are oft-asked obvious duplicates (I dupe-voted for an exact one), and thus certainly not deserving of any upvotes. (@Brad: Yes, I know, and was not trying to criticize your answer, only add something more.)

Comment: @Deduplicator No problem. I posted the comment after your edit that makes that obvious. Thanks for adding the notes!

Answer (score 8):

It should be closed because there are literally dozens of duplicates that can be found with a quick search for "reverse words sentence". I stopped counting after a few pages of search results.

This question coming up here so many times is no big surprise. This might be the most frequently asked programming question in interviews. I never use it because I assume that every candidate would already be familiar with the solution.

Comment: Yet, you will be surprised how many candidates cannot pass this bar

Answer (score 5):

- "Is this a valid question?" Certainly it is. It's a clearly scoped, generic programming issue with well defined expected result and some code to illustrate what has been tried.
- "Will it help future researchers?" It has certainly potential for this, as there seem to be lot of people working on the same issue. However, question could certainly be improved.
- "It's a simple-to-solve problem with having everything needed at hand." - is this a problem? Shouldn't questions ideally be like this in stack overflow?

The main problem is that there are a lot of duplicates which are in better shape than this. So, vote to close as a duplicate. The question in itself is certainly valid (even if not of very high quality).

Comment: Finding duplicates is part of "research", so most plenty of people will downvote based on the fact no effort to find duplicate shown. (Unless gold-hammer comes fast enough)

Answer (score 3):

I admit I upvoted the question. My reason for upvoting was it did show an attempt and had a clear problem statement. I found a true duplicate question a bit later and voted to close the question.

I don't think it deserved as many downvotes as it got. Downvoting without an explanation is helpful to no one. It is better to point out where the duplicates are and/or where the answer can be found. Opting to close with proper explanation is, in my opinion, more helpful than downvoting without any explanation.

Comment: Did you realise you could both downvote and closevote? Also, you shouldn't be giving A's for effort.

Comment: Well, that's depressing. The question says "I'm not getting the correct output" - but never bothers to even say what *is* happening. You don't have to downvote or even vote to close if you don't want to, but it hardly deserves to be *rewarded* as-is.

Comment: @JanDvorak, of course I do. I can see the smirk on your face when you wrote that.

Comment: @pnuts: Actually, if you don't know that's an abundantly re-asked duplicate off-hand, you obviously don't frequent any relevant tags. And there were other problems.

Comment: @AndrewMedico actually it does say - in the comments of the source code.