# How is this horrible question considered on topic

Tags: discussion, bad-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552349/checks-whether-the-digits-of-a-number-form-increasing-sequence-c

How is this considered on topic, and why are high-rep users encouraging "Here's my code, find my bug " questions?

- The OP posted the entirety of their code; they didnt reduce it to the smallest portion needed to reproduce.
  -- (Probably because they never attempted to figure out what they did wrong)
- OP has not specified a clear problem with their code. All they have said is "I have some arbitrary goal to do X, here's my attempt, why is my code wrong".   What's the problem? What statement or function isn't working, where does your logic break down?
- OP has not done the due diligence of even stepping through a debugger
- OP has not demonstrated what they have done to try to solve the problem. Did they look on SO, did they look on Google? Did they consult a manual of any kind?  No probabaly not because they haven't even defined what's wrong with their code other than "it doesnt give me the value I want"

Granted we can see the answer here; min should have been set to 0 initially arguably... but as written this answer helps no one, and teaches the author nothing.  No one will benefit from this..  Case in point, look at the answer the user got and basically accepted.  "Ooh thanks for the codes" he says.

High Rep user claims : "posting their code constitutes an attempt to solve the problem"  I completely dispute this and say that THAT is them posting the problem they created; otherwise everyone who posts the code they've tried is on topic.  Is that really a precedent we want to set?  You can't attempt to solve a problem you haven't defined.  They have to show an attempt at solving the problem they are presenting, not the goal of their software.  To do that they have to define a problem; OP hasn't: OP has only defined a context that his problem and solution lie in.

So what's the deal here?

Comment: I have no problem down/close voting it.  In fact, I now have.

Comment: Note that it's not really feasible to post on meta every time you see a bad post get answered and not closed.  This kind of thing happens thousands of times every single day.  It's unfortunate, but posting on meta every time you see it just isn't a practical solution to the problem; it just doesn't scale.  This (I suspect/hope) is the reason for the downvotes on this meta question.  You seem to clearly understand that (and why) this is a bad question, so there's not really much for us to tell you other than, "yep, this sucks".

Comment: ^^ quite.  If I tried, I would get barred from meta for spamming:(

Comment: In this case, I especially enjoyed 'Using microsoft Visual studio-2015' - OP has an IDE debugger with panes for vars, locals/stack etc, a stepping cursor, mouse-tip expression evaluation etc. and so...... no, post immediate on SO:(

Comment: @MartinJames yeah that was my favorite part.. what's the excuse?

Comment: @Servy yep; mostly wanted to make sure I didn't suddenly misunderstand something because the wording on the close page changed..   But there must be SOMETHING we can do?

Comment: To note: downvoting an answer because you dislike the question is not doing anyone any benefit. Vote based on content. If you took issues with the content of the answer fine, but using a vote as a punitive "WHY ARE YOU ANSWERING" is flat out ridiculous and harms the community.

Comment: [One of the answerers' point of view](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276618/2564301). At least he's not fickle, and stands by his principles.

Comment: @TravisJ assuming that's towards me; I didn't really downvote the answer ( i did, but i undid it immediately... and commented instead and posted here instead )

Comment: @UpAndAdam - From your comment (http://i.imgur.com/QsoKZwJ.png) and the direction of this post, that is an interpretation other people will take. The note was not just directed at you, this is conversation that as a community we have had dozens of times over the years and the conclusion is that downvoting answers punitively does not help the problem of poorly asked questions. Action the content, if the question is poor, then downvote and close. Same with the answer. But please avoid calling out users just for answering like that as it doesn't really benefit anyone.

Comment: When the content of an answer is encouraging people to answer awful off topic questions, then they deserve a downvote.

Comment: When you attack answers, you get less answers. This is true of both poor quality and high quality questions. Driving away people who would be answering questions is not a solution to limiting awful off topic questions.

Comment: @Jongware That just makes it worse; he's doing this rampantly.   The problem is that his principle is ill constructed.  By his definition any question of the form "here's my codez I can haz answer" is acceptable because they want through the trouble of posting the code which constitutes their 'attempt'.  The 'problem' is not the goal of their code. He doesn't get this. The problem is "why your code isn't doing what you think it should be".

Comment: I agree, it is just making things worse to answer these questions. Which is why they should be closed faster so that no answers can be posted and the asking ban can be triggered quicker. If anyone has ideas on how to approach the cause (job shop questions) and not the symptoms (teh codez answers) please post an answer here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308837/1026459

Comment: @travisj i would completely disagree with you. its the complete LACK of accountability for any of the so called high rep users who are supposed to do things properly that is the cause of this problem...  We constantly have discussions about being nicer to new users, notice how we NEVER say be nicer to high rep people?  The whole system here is to give people 'permission to do stuff' and increase their rep based on them following the rules... through learned behavior.  So is that meaningless too??

Comment: @UpAndAdam - Feel free to actually post your concerns in an answer because you aren't disagreeing with me, you are disagreeing with community consensus. You realize the high level of duplication going on in this discussion right? There is a certain level of irony that this entire post is more of a rant with no nod to historical discussion and yet its topic is about questions who do not show enough research effort or explanation.

Comment: Here is some of the research you should have done: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255460/1026459 , http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252070/1026459 , http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286236/1026459 , http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255805/1026459 , http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/1026459

Comment: Here is a post addressing the concern that we need more answers, and that in general answering is in decline http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252756/1026459

Comment: @TravisJ The answers are *bad answers*.  They're harmful to the site, the author of the question, and future visitors.  The reason that they're harmful is of course *indirectly* related to the fact that the question is horrible.  When you ask an unanswerable question then the answers will *by definition*, not be good answers.  If you downvote the answer you're still downvoting it because the answer is bad, but the answer is often bad out of necessity of the question being bad.  People going around upvoting the crap answers to the crap questions *is why we keep seeing more crap questions*.

Comment: @Servy - Upvoting is *definitely* counter productive in that scenario. If you see an answer whose content is incorrect or problematic, then naturally it is can be downvoted for being "bad". That said, people with pitchforks out in force downvoting every answer to every question they issue a close vote to is far more problematic. There is no evidence to support that taking the approach you suggest is a solution. There is only evidence to the contrary that downvoting answers solely based on the question causes less answers to be posted in the future - even to good questions.

Comment: @Servy You use the term "harmful" here, and there has never been any actual proven association that answering is harmful in this situation. While the answer may not be productive, there is no correlation to it causing harm. Historically, we (me and you) have discussed this topic many times. I think there is a post somewhere with like 70 comments on this topic. No matter how many times we discuss this though, the main issue is that we need a solution to address the questions. Many users spent a lot of time downvoting answers to off topic questions and it got us nowhere. We need something else.

Comment: @TravisJ Why do people like you assume that every bad answer to a bad question shouldn't be downvoted, even though it's bad?  The answer is bad; it's being downvoted because it's bad.  The fact that the answer is bad because the question is so bad that it's impossible to post a good answer doesn't mean that the answer is any less bad, or should somehow be spared a downvote *for posting an unhelpful answer*.

Comment: @TravisJ Downvoting the bad answers does indeed get us nowhere, and that's because people upvote the bad answers, and often do so all the more when they have downvotes.  So long as more people want bad content then there are people who want good content, we won't be able to get rid of the bad content.  It doesn't make it right, but it is the reality we live in.

Comment: @Servy - I didn't say that, I said that every answer to off topic questions is not immediately bad, and should be voted on based on content. You can look at my profile, I do downvote. I am not saying not to downvote, and especially am not advocating pity upvoting. I am merely saying not to downvote for the sole purpose of making a statement not to answer questions that are "bad".

Comment: @Servy - We will *never* be able to get rid of bad content, which is why *prevention* is the best possible scenario. We need more signal to identify which users or questions need to be prevented through automation. This is why addressing and actioning the question is far more reliable for sending signal. Downvoting an answer does not increase that signal so it does not contribute to a solution. The signal downvoting an answer sends is that the content posted in the answer is not useful to the question's problem. Those are two very different metrics.

Comment: @TravisJ Nobody *is* saying that.  You're making a straw man argument.  People keep accusing those who are downvoting bad answers to bad questions of downvoting the answers just because the question is bad.  Bad questions lead to bad answers; that's part of what makes them bad questions.  That a question is bad means that it's *very* likely to attract bad answers, so having a bad question with a lot of bad answers is *very* common.  Downvoting those bad answers is helpful.  You're observing a correlation in voting patterns and accusing people of voting because of a causation.

Comment: @TravisJ When you upvote the bad answers to bad questions, people post more bad answers to bad questions.  When people's bad questions get more answers, they post more bad questions.  When people's questions don't get answers, then they do what they need to do to get answers, which (if we do our job well) means fixing the question into a *quality* question.  But not amount of closing bad questions while upvoting the bad answers that were posted before the question gets closed will do a thing to stop help vampires.

Comment: @Servy - I am not observing a correlation, I am sitting here having read hours of meta posts about users directly stating they downvoted to punish an answer for answering, even when it was not a bad answer. This is not a strawman, it is straight historical precedence. While you are clearly aware of the nuance involved in the posts you view, many are not.

Comment: @Servy - I am not upvoting these answers. However, I do agree that they get upvotes for whatever reason, and often. Why not address that though? Trying to change something socially when there are 3 million users and only 15,000 of them are downvoting is *never going to work*. If you cannot provide a solution that works with an automated system then anything you attempt will just be your personal agenda and not an effort of community.

Comment: @TravisJ If I knew of a solution, I'd propose one.  I don't see a way of fixing the fact that a majority of the users of the site want to see more bad content.  I've already said as much (multiple times, in this very meta question).

Comment: @Servy - Okay, well, do a majority of users want to see more bad content? How would you measure that?

Comment: @TravisJ yes you are right, i should have searched more. the challenge is that many of our posts and discussions have taken places at different times when it seemed like community stance ( and the flags available for closing ) were different.  But you are right in the end I am bringing in a new bad post over to 'meta'.  Perhaps that's a different feature idea; a way to mark a discussion that is no longer 'precedent' because the rules have changed. ( good examples include 'too minor edits' )... You are both right though upvoting makes worse, down vote is a hopeless crusade. automation or bust

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How is this considered on topic

It's not.  It's just depressingly hard to find 5 people that actually care to vote to close.

> why are high-rep users encouraging "Here's my code, find my bug " questions?

Because it's a quick and easy way to earn lots of rep, despite the fact that, as you described, it's not useful for anyone involved (the answerer, future readers, and the OP are all *harmed* by these answers).

If people didn't upvote these answers to offtopic questions (and usually quite a lot; thanks to the bikeshed effect) then there wouldn't be so many people so inclined to post answers to them.  Downvotes to these answers also tend to just get overcompensated by pity upvotes by people that think any answer that's technically correct shouldn't be downvoted, regardless of how useful or harmful it is.

Comment: Finally we agree on something!!! LOL

Comment: I downvoted both the who.. whoever answered.

Comment: @MartinJames I would if I didn't know it's just result in pity upvotes.